# Doctrine find() function is working but it is returning DQL first then the object. I don't want to display DQL

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

my code is

```
public function index() {

        $user = $this->doctrine->em->find('user\models\User', 1);

        echo '<br>';      

        echo $user->getName();
}
```

output is

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2 FROM tbl_user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "integer" }
```

john

I have used CodeIgniter 2.2.2 and I have integrated doctrine using these steps [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I had to comment the EchoSQLLogger() in Doctrine.php file in the libraries folder.

```
    // Set up logger
    //$logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    //$config->setSQLLogger($logger);
```